# Initializing objects using Objective-C, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c

if **header** file declares

```
@interface SomeClass: NSObject {
  Data* d;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Data* d;
```

Why is the following line in the **implementation** file giving me a warning (and `init` method does not get called?)

```
[[[self d] alloc] init];
```

The warning i get is

> *Instance method '-alloc' not found (return type defaults to 'id')*

Meanwhile, `Data` has
`- (id) init` method, that is not being called.

Please help me understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`alloc` should be invoked on a **class**, not on an **instance**.

```
interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
    Data *d;
}
```

Declare an init method on SomeClass and make it look like:

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init]; 
    if (self)
    {
        d = [[Data alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [d release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now you do:

```
SomeClass *c = [[SomeClass init] alloc];
```

And you can use the class. Note that you should probably read a little more on classes and objects and about memory management too (when you should release c, etc.).

If, by any chance, you have the possibility to use ARC (automatic reference counting), you won't need to take care of releasing stuff. But that doesn't come with Xcode 4.1, only with 4.2 which is not publicly accessible, apparently.

Comment: Rudy - why is [self d] an instance of a class?

Comment: Because you declared it as such: `d` is a pointer to an instance of type `Data`, and `[self d]` is a reference to that. `d` is not the class `Data`. `alloc` is a class method, and should be called on a class, like `Data`, not on an instance, like `d`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't `-(id)init`, it's `-(id)alloc`. alloc is a *class* method of NSObject, which means you send it to the class itself and not to an instance of that class, i.e.:

```
[Data alloc]; // Correct
[someDataInstance alloc]; // Method not found
```

When you call `[self d]`, you're given an instance of a Data, which you're then sending a -(id)alloc message to. Since NSObject doesn't have a `-(id)alloc` (only a `+(id)alloc`), you get the warning.

Comment: (Strictly speaking, if you do `[self d]` before `d` has been initialized, you don't get an instance, but that's just nitpicking that delayed me posting an answer because I was trying to figure out how to express it succinctly. :)

Comment: @Josh - I was thinking the same thing. If d is a pointer to Data, [self d] should return me a pointer to a class which i then initialize.

Comment: @Josh, correct, you get nil, which just quietly fails, and is why he isn't crashing with an unrecognized selector :) I figured it was a distraction from the main point.

Comment: Guys - why in this example [self d] is an instance of a class and not a pointer to a class?

Comment: @mac, with this terminology, a pointer to Data is synonymous to an instance of Data. It's tempting to think of this is C-like terms, where you would take a pointer, then malloc some memory for it. In Objective-C, the actual mallocing is handled internally by the class that you are allocating. Thus, you don't allocate a pointer to an object directly, you ask the class to do that for you.

Comment: @mac -- a pointer to a class would look like: `Class c = [Data class];` You could then do `[[c alloc] init];` The class name (`Data`, e.g.) can also be used as a target to send messages, as in `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]` What you have there is a pointer to an instance. (Matt -- you're right, it's ancillary.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing

```
self.d = [[Data alloc] init];
```

As Matt says, `alloc` is a class method, and must be called on the class itself.